# How to check the properties of an object equal to some value?

Tags: javascript

in the code below I want to print the values of "years_of_experience" which is less than 34 and birthplace which is equal to "texas". But I'm not getting how to write the statement correctly

```
var  employees = [
    {
       name1:'jacob',
       age2 : 23,
       date_of_join : 23/03/2013,
       years_of_experience : 12,
       birth_place: "virginia" 
    },
    {
       name2:'sheldon',
       age2 : 34,
       date_of_join :2/03/2013,
       years_of_experience : 15,
       birth_place: "lisbon"  
    },
    {
       name3:'johnny',
       age3 : 25,
       date_of_join :29/03/2013,
       years_of_experience : 13,
       birth_place: "texas"  
    }];

    employees.forEach(function(a) {
        console.log(a);
     });
        for(var i = 0;i <= employees.length;i++)
            {
                if(employees[i]!= -1)
                {
                    console.log("gotcha");
                    if(employees.hasOwnProperty === years_of_experience) < 34 || (employees.hasOwnProperty(birth_place) === "teaxs")
                    {
//here i want to print the values of  
//  "years_of_experience"  which is less than 34 and birthplace which is equal to   
// "texas".But i'm not getting how to write the statement for that become m new to 
// javascript and even m not sure i've written the conditional statement right,
// please correct it and help me.. 


                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: [Any specific question?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: if(employees[i]["years_of_experience"] < 34 || (employees[i]["birth_place"] === "texas")

Comment: hey thanx Lion for making the conditional statement write but how i will print the values which i will get from the condition after getting true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(employees[i].years_of_experience < 34 || employees[i].birth_place === "teaxs")
```

Comment: hey thanx how to print the value of "years_of_experience " and "texas"

Comment: console.log("Year of Experience: \n"+ employees[i].years_of_experience+ "\nBirth Place: "+employees[i].birth_place);

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it easy to seperate

Comment: Thnx Tamil Selvan for help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you misspelled 'texas'

[`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is a method, not a property and also it doesn't pull the value from a property, it simply returns a `boolean` of whether it has or does not have that property.

You may want something like the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

    if (employees[i].hasOwnProperty("years_of_experience") && employees[i].hasOwnProperty("birth_place")) {
        if (employees[i].years_of_experience < 34 || employees[i].birth_place === "texas") {
            console.log("Year of Experience: \n" + employees[i].years_of_experience + "\nBirth Place: " + employees[i].birth_place);
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/Pycd4/5/) : Check your console.

You should also change your "date_of_join" into a string if that's the way you want to store dates. Right now you are getting a very obscure decimal value.

```
var employees = [{
    ...
    date_of_join: "23 / 03 / 2013",
    ...
}, {
    ...
    date_of_join: "2 / 03 / 2013",
    ...
}, {
    ...
    date_of_join: "29 / 03 / 2013",
    ...
}];
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot ChristopherW ,but what if i want to print the value of "years_of_experience" and "texas",,what statement i have to write for that please mention?

Comment: @user1976940 check out the for loop now.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
var years = employees[i]["years_of_experience"]; 
var POB = employees[i]["birth_place"];
if (years < 34 || POB === "texas") {
  document.getElementById("idOfSomeTag").innerHTML = "Years:" years +", POB"+POB;
  // or console.log("years",years,"Pob",POB);
}
```